# How to set the view to the active cell in PHPSpreadsheet?

Tags: excel, phpspreadsheet

I'm using PHPSpreadsheet and I'm setting cell via $sht->setActiveCell("C1").  It is working; when I open Excel, the active cell indicator shows C1.  Problem is, the actual view in the spreadsheet is at row 409 where the data ends.

Is there a way to tell it to ensure the view is on the selected row?  GPT said that isn't possible, as it's a function of the client not the generating software (which makes sense) but I wanted to verify as GPT can be wrong quite often.

Thanks!